# MIPS program to get two integers from the user, save it to an array, and print it

Tags: arrays, mips

I am trying to write a MIPS assembly program to get two integers from the user, save it to the memory in an array and print it. This is what i have so far. My program prints some big number  that I didn't put in. I am very new to this game. Somebody help please!

Here's my code:

```
.text
.globl main

    main:
        li $v0, 4       
        la $a0, prompt  
        syscall

        li $t0, 0      #count for the loop to get two integers
    getnum:
        li $v0, 5   #read integer
        syscall
        sw $v0, num($s0)    #save the integer from user input into num and $s0 has address for num, I'm not sure if i did this right
        addi $s0, $s0, 4    # increment $s0 by 4 to save another integer
        addi $t0, $t0, 1    #increment the counter
        ble $t0, 1, getnum       #if counter $t0, is less then or equal to 1, it will go through the loop again

    printnum:   
        la $a0, num($s0)        #load address of num to print
        li $v0, 1           #print int
        syscall 
        addi $s0, $s0, 4    
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        ble $t1, 1, printnum        #does it twice

        li $v0, 10  
        syscall
.data 

    num:
         .word 0, 0  # i want to store my two numbers here
    prompt: 
        .asciiz "Enter 2 positive integers: "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are two fold.

First, you are loading the address of the integer instead of the actual integer. To fix this change `la` to `lw`.

Secondly, because you increment `$s0` twice in the `getnum` loop and immediately use it in the `printnum` loop it is too far ahead, you will need to add `move $s0, $zero` to solve this problem.

In addition, your code seems to rely on the fact that `$s0` starts the program with a value of 0, which isn't perhaps a great assumption to make. It would be better to explicitly set it to zero.

Comment: Isn't the use accessing of array incorrect as well? When @pdhimal1 tries to store and load words using `num($s0)` shouldn't it be `$s0(num)`? Essentially the format is `register(indexValue)` when it should be `indexValue(register)`